# How does epoll's EPOLLEXCLUSIVE mode interact with level-triggering?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

Suppose the following series of events occurs:

- We set up a listening socket
- Thread A blocks waiting for the listening socket to become readable, using `EPOLLIN | EPOLLEXCLUSIVE`
- Thread B also blocks waiting for the listening socket to become readable, also using `EPOLLIN | EPOLLEXCLUSIVE`
- An incoming connection arrives at the listening socket, making the socket readable, and the kernel elects to wake up thread A.
- But, before the thread actually wakes up and calls `accept`, a second incoming connection arrives at the listening socket.

Here, the socket is already readable, so the second connection doesn't change that. This is level-triggered epoll, so according to the normal rules, the second connection can be treated as a no-op, and the second thread doesn't need to be awoken. ...Of course, *not* waking up the second thread would kind of defeat the whole purpose of `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE`? But my trust in API designers doing the right thing is not as strong as it once was, and I can't find anything in the documentation to rule this out.

**Questions**

a) Is the above scenario possible, where two connections arrive but only thread is woken? Or is it guaranteed that every distinct incoming connection on a listening socket will wake another thread?

b) Is there a general rule to predict how `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` and level-triggered epoll interact?

b) What about `EPOLLIN | EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` and `EPOLLOUT | EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` for byte-stream fds, like a connected TCP socket or a pipe? E.g. what happens if more data arrives while a pipe is already readable?

Comment: The documentation looks pretty clear to me on this: setting `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` is supposed to return from *at least one* `epoll_wait()` in contrast to all of them w/o it. This was introduced to avoid thundering herd behaviour. Level-triggered guarantees that `epoll_wait()` returns as long as the wake-up condition persists (although some recommend to loop until `EAGAIN` for being faster than `epoll`). Both aspects are orthogonal. The actual implementation may show some interference, but that is nothing one should rely on. If the implementation breaks one of its guarantees, that would be a bug.

Comment: ...I can't tell from your comment what you think the actual behavior is though :-). You can't have `epoll_wait` simultaneously "return as long as the wake-up condition persists" and *also* have only one `epoll_wait` return – these are logically inconsistent. Which is fine, but I still don't know how the inconsistency is resolved. (+ in the intended application of multi-process listen servers, every new connection triggering a new wakeup would actually be the ideal behavior.)

Comment: What actually happens is very dependent on the kernel implementation: I *guess* the callback for the second connect would schedule thread B, as A has been removed from the wait queue before. But don't take my word for it. Anyway, the only guarantee given is, that `epoll_wait()` returns until there are no more pending connections (i.e. `accept()` would return `EAGAIN`).

Comment: ... oh, and I do not think that there is a logical inconsistency. The guarantee is not that *only one* `epoll_wait()` returns, but that *at least one* one returns as long as the condition persists. I.e. if `epoll` behaved with `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` the same as without, it would be consistent with the documented guarantees.

Comment: Right, the inconsistency is that immediately *after* the first `epoll_wait` returns, then you have the situation where: the condition is true, and there are some `epoll_wait`s that are waiting for it, yet... none of them are returning. This is not how level-triggered waiting works, normally. One or more of them will return, eventually. The question is, what triggers this?

Comment: I do not think that "none of them are returning" can actually happen when there are pending connections and `EPOLLET` was not used -- that would be a bug. With LT, the return from `epoll_wait()` is simply triggered by the kernel checking for pending "events" on the fd. This checking is avoided with `EPOLLET`, which therefore is a possible optimiziation, but changes semantics compared to `poll`.

Answer (score 19):

**Edited** (original answer is after the code used for testing)

To make sure things are clear, I'll go over `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` as it relates to edge triggered events (`EPOLLET`) as well as level-triggered events, to show how these effect expected behavior.

As you well know:

- **Edge Triggered**: Once you set `EPOLLET`, events are triggered only if they change the state of the `fd` - meaning that only the first event is triggered and no new events will get triggered until that event is fully handled.

  This design is explicitly meant to prevent `epoll_wait` from returning due to an event that is in the process of being handled (i.e., when new data arrives while the `EPOLLIN` was already raised but `read` hadn't been called or not all of the data was read).

  The edge-triggered event rule is simple **all same-type (i.e. `EPOLLIN`) events are *merged* until all available data was processed**.

  In the case of a listening socket, the `EPOLLIN` event won't be triggered again until all existing `listen` "backlog" sockets have been accepted using `accept`.

  In the case of a byte stream, new events won't be triggered until all the the available bytes have been read from the stream (the buffer was emptied).
- **Level Triggered**: On the other hand, level triggered events will behave closer to how legacy `select` (or `poll`) operates, allowing `epoll` to be used with older code.

  The event-merger rule is more complex: **events of the same type are only merged if no one is waiting for an event** (no one is waiting for `epoll_wait` to return), **or if multiple events happen before `epoll_wait` can return**... otherwise any event causes `epoll_wait` to return.

  In the case of a listening socket, the `EPOLLIN` event will be triggered every time a client connects... unless no one is waiting for `epoll_wait` to return, in which case the next call for `epoll_wait` will return immediately and all the `EPOLLIN` events that occurred during that time will have been merged into a single event.

  In the case of a byte stream, new events will be triggered every time new data comes in... unless, of course, no one is waiting for `epoll_wait` to return, in which case the next call will return immediately for all the data that arrive util `epoll_wait` returned (even if it arrived in different chunks / events).
- **Exclusive return**: The `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` flag is used to prevent the "thundering heard" behavior, so only a single `epoll_wait` caller is woken up for each `fd` wake-up event.

  As I pointed out before, for edge-triggered states, an `fd` wake-up event is a **change** in the `fd` state. So all `EPOLLIN` events will be raised until all data was read (the listening socket's backlog was emptied).

  On the other hand, for level triggered events, each `EPOLLIN` will invoke a wake up event. If no one is waiting, these events will be merged.

Following the example in your question:

- **For level triggered events**: every time a client connects, a single thread will return from `epoll_wait`... BUT, if two more clients were to connect while both threads were busy accepting the first two clients, these `EPOLLIN` events would merge into a single event and the next call to `epoll_wait` will return immediately with that merged event.

  In the context of the example given in the question, thread B is expected to "wake up" due to `epoll_wait` returning.

  In this case, both threads will "race" towards `accept`.

  However, this doesn't defeat the `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` directive or intent.

  The `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` directive is meant to prevent the "thundering heard" phenomenon. In this case, two threads are racing to accept two connections. Each thread can (presumably) call `accept` safely, with no errors. If three threads were used, the third would keep on sleeping.

  If the `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` weren't used, all the `epoll_wait` threads would have been woken up whenever a connection was available, meaning that as soon as the first connection arrived, both threads would have been racing to accept a single connection (resulting in a possible error for one of them).
- **For edge triggered events**: only one thread is expected to receive the "wake up" call. That thread is expected to `accept` all waiting connections (empty the `listen` "backlog"). No more `EPOLLIN` events will be raised for that socket until the backlog is emptied.

The same applies to readable sockets and pipes. The thread that was woken up is expected to deal with all the readable data. This prevents to waiting threads from attempting to read the data concurrently and experiencing file lock race conditions.

I would recommend (and this is what I do) to set the listening socket to non-blocking mode and calling `accept` in a loop until an `EAGAIN` (or `EWOULDBLOCK`) error is raised, indicating that the backlog is empty. There is no way to avoid the risk of events being merged. The same is true for reading from a socket.

**Testing this with code**:

I wrote a simple test, with some `sleep` commands and blocking sockets. Client sockets are initiated only after both threads start waiting for `epoll`.

Client thread initiation is delayed, so client 1 and client 2 start a second apart.

Once a server thread is woken up, it will sleep for a second (allowing the second client to do it's thing) before calling `accept`. Maybe the servers should sleep a little more, but it seems close enough to manage the scheduler without resorting to conditional variables.

Here are the results of my test code (which might be a mess, I'm not the best person for test design)...

On Ubuntu 16.10, which supports `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE`, the test results show that the listening threads are woken up one after the other, in response to the clients. In the example in the question, thread B is woken up.

```
Test address: <null>:8000
Server thread 2 woke up with 1 events
Server thread 2 will sleep for a second, to let things happen.
client number 1 connected
Server thread 1 woke up with 1 events
Server thread 1 will sleep for a second, to let things happen.
client number 2 connected
Server thread 2 accepted a connection and saying hello.
client 1: Hello World - from server thread 2.
Server thread 1 accepted a connection and saying hello.
client 2: Hello World - from server thread 1.
```

To compare with Ubuntu 16.04 (without `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` support), than both threads are woken up for the first connection. Since I use blocking sockets, the second thread hangs on `accept` until client # 2 connects.

```
main.c:178:2: warning: #warning EPOLLEXCLUSIVE undeclared, test is futile [-Wcpp]
 #warning EPOLLEXCLUSIVE undeclared, test is futile
  ^
Test address: <null>:8000
Server thread 1 woke up with 1 events
Server thread 1 will sleep for a second, to let things happen.
Server thread 2 woke up with 1 events
Server thread 2 will sleep for a second, to let things happen.
client number 1 connected
Server thread 1 accepted a connection and saying hello.
client 1: Hello World - from server thread 1.
client number 2 connected
Server thread 2 accepted a connection and saying hello.
client 2: Hello World - from server thread 2.
```

For one more comparison, the results for level triggered `kqueue` show that both threads are awoken for the first connection. Since I use blocking sockets, the second thread hangs on `accept` until client # 2 connects.

```
Test address: <null>:8000
client number 1 connected
Server thread 2 woke up with 1 events
Server thread 1 woke up with 1 events
Server thread 2 will sleep for a second, to let things happen.
Server thread 1 will sleep for a second, to let things happen.
Server thread 2 accepted a connection and saying hello.
client 1: Hello World - from server thread 2.
client number 2 connected
Server thread 1 accepted a connection and saying hello.
client 2: Hello World - from server thread 1.
```

My test code was (sorry for the lack of comments and the messy code, I wasn't writing for future maintenance):

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#define ADD_EPOLL_OPTION 0 // define as EPOLLET or 0

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#if !defined(__linux__) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
#include <sys/event.h>
#define reactor_epoll 0
#else
#define reactor_epoll 1
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#endif

int sock_listen(const char *address, const char *port);
void *listen_threard(void *arg);
void *client_thread(void *arg);
int server_fd;
char const *address = NULL;
char const *port = "8000";

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  if (argc == 2) {
    port = argv[1];
  } else if (argc == 3) {
    port = argv[2];
    address = argv[1];
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "Test address: %s:%s\n", address ? address : "<null>", port);
  server_fd = sock_listen(address, port);
  /* code */
  pthread_t threads[4];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, listen_threard, (void *)i))
      perror("couldn't initiate server thread"), exit(-1);
  }
  for (size_t i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
    sleep(1);
    if (pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, client_thread, (void *)i))
      perror("couldn't initiate client thread"), exit(-1);
  }
  // join only server threads.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  close(server_fd);
  sleep(1);
  return 0;
}

/**
Sets a socket to non blocking state.
*/
inline int sock_set_non_block(int fd) // Thanks to Bjorn Reese
{
/* If they have O_NONBLOCK, use the Posix way to do it */
#if defined(O_NONBLOCK)
  /* Fixme: O_NONBLOCK is defined but broken on SunOS 4.1.x and AIX 3.2.5. */
  int flags;
  if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)))
    flags = 0;
  // printf("flags initial value was %d\n", flags);
  return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
#else
  /* Otherwise, use the old way of doing it */
  static int flags = 1;
  return ioctl(fd, FIOBIO, &flags);
#endif
}

/* open a listenning socket */
int sock_listen(const char *address, const char *port) {
  int srvfd;
  // setup the address
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *servinfo;       // will point to the results
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); // make sure the struct is empty
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     // don't care IPv4 or IPv6
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP stream sockets
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me
  if (getaddrinfo(address, port, &hints, &servinfo)) {
    perror("addr err");
    return -1;
  }
  // get the file descriptor
  srvfd =
      socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);
  if (srvfd <= 0) {
    perror("socket err");
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    return -1;
  }
  // // keep the server socket blocking for the test.
  // // make sure the socket is non-blocking
  // if (sock_set_non_block(srvfd) < 0) {
  //   perror("couldn't set socket as non blocking! ");
  //   freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
  //   close(srvfd);
  //   return -1;
  // }

  // avoid the "address taken"
  {
    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(srvfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));
  }
  // bind the address to the socket
  {
    int bound = 0;
    for (struct addrinfo *p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
      if (!bind(srvfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen))
        bound = 1;
    }

    if (!bound) {
      // perror("bind err");
      freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
      close(srvfd);
      return -1;
    }
  }
  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
  // listen in
  if (listen(srvfd, SOMAXCONN) < 0) {
    perror("couldn't start listening");
    close(srvfd);
    return -1;
  }
  return srvfd;
}
/* will start listenning, sleep for 5 seconds, then accept all the backlog and
 * finish */
void *listen_threard(void *arg) {

  int epoll_fd;
  ssize_t event_count;
#if reactor_epoll

#ifndef EPOLLEXCLUSIVE
#warning EPOLLEXCLUSIVE undeclared, test is futile
#define EPOLLEXCLUSIVE 0
#endif
  // create the epoll wait fd
  epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
  if (epoll_fd < 0)
    perror("couldn't create epoll fd"), exit(1);
  // add the server fd to the epoll watchlist
  {
    struct epoll_event chevent = {0};
    chevent.data.ptr = (void *)((uintptr_t)server_fd);
    chevent.events =
        EPOLLOUT | EPOLLIN | EPOLLERR | EPOLLEXCLUSIVE | ADD_EPOLL_OPTION;
    epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, server_fd, &chevent);
  }
  // wait with epoll
  struct epoll_event events[10];
  event_count = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, 10, 5000);
#else
  // testing on BSD, use kqueue
  epoll_fd = kqueue();
  if (epoll_fd < 0)
    perror("couldn't create kqueue fd"), exit(1);
  // add the server fd to the kqueue watchlist
  {
    struct kevent chevent[2];
    EV_SET(chevent, server_fd, EVFILT_READ, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE, 0, 0,
           (void *)((uintptr_t)server_fd));
    EV_SET(chevent + 1, server_fd, EVFILT_WRITE, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE, 0, 0,
           (void *)((uintptr_t)server_fd));
    kevent(epoll_fd, chevent, 2, NULL, 0, NULL);
  }
  // wait with kqueue
  static struct timespec reactor_timeout = {.tv_sec = 5, .tv_nsec = 0};
  struct kevent events[10];
  event_count = kevent(epoll_fd, NULL, 0, events, 10, &reactor_timeout);
#endif

  close(epoll_fd);

  if (event_count <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server thread %lu wakeup no events / error\n",
            (size_t)arg + 1);
    perror("errno ");
    return NULL;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "Server thread %lu woke up with %lu events\n",
          (size_t)arg + 1, event_count);
  fprintf(stderr,
          "Server thread %lu will sleep for a second, to let things happen.\n",
          (size_t)arg + 1);
  sleep(1);
  int connfd;
  struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
  socklen_t client_addrlen = sizeof client_addr;
  /* accept up all connections. we're non-blocking, -1 == no more connections */
  if ((connfd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,
                       &client_addrlen)) >= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Server thread %lu accepted a connection and saying hello.\n",
            (size_t)arg + 1);
    if (write(connfd, arg ? "Hello World - from server thread 2."
                          : "Hello World - from server thread 1.",
              35) < 35)
      perror("server write failed");
    close(connfd);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server thread %lu failed to accept a connection",
            (size_t)arg + 1);
    perror(": ");
  }
  return NULL;
}

void *client_thread(void *arg) {

  int fd;
  // setup the address
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *addrinfo;       // will point to the results
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); // make sure the struct is empty
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     // don't care IPv4 or IPv6
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP stream sockets
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me
  if (getaddrinfo(address, port, &hints, &addrinfo)) {
    perror("client couldn't initiate address");
    return NULL;
  }
  // get the file descriptor
  fd =
      socket(addrinfo->ai_family, addrinfo->ai_socktype, addrinfo->ai_protocol);
  if (fd <= 0) {
    perror("client couldn't create socket");
    freeaddrinfo(addrinfo);
    return NULL;
  }
  // // // Leave the socket blocking for the test.
  // // make sure the socket is non-blocking
  // if (sock_set_non_block(fd) < 0) {
  //   freeaddrinfo(addrinfo);
  //   close(fd);
  //   return -1;
  // }

  if (connect(fd, addrinfo->ai_addr, addrinfo->ai_addrlen) < 0 &&
      errno != EINPROGRESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "client number %lu FAILED\n", (size_t)arg - 1);
    perror("client connect failure");
    close(fd);
    freeaddrinfo(addrinfo);
    return NULL;
  }
  freeaddrinfo(addrinfo);
  fprintf(stderr, "client number %lu connected\n", (size_t)arg - 1);
  char buffer[128];
  if (read(fd, buffer, 35) < 35) {
    perror("client: read error");
    close(fd);
  } else {
    buffer[35] = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "client %lu: %s\n", (size_t)arg - 1, buffer);
    close(fd);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

**P.S.**

As a final recommendation, I would consider having no more than a single thread and a single epoll `fd` per process. This way the "thundering heard" is a non-issue and `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` (which is still very new and isn't widely supported) can be disregarded... the only "thundering heard" this still exposes is for the limited amount of shared sockets, where the race condition might be good for load balancing.

---

**Original Answer**

I'm not sure I understand the confusion, so I'll go over `EPOLLET` and `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` to show their combined expected behavior.

As you well know:

- Once you set `EPOLLET` (edge triggered), events are triggered on `fd` state **changes** rather than `fd` events.

  This design is explicitly meant to prevent `epoll_wait` from returning due to an event that is in the process of being handled (i.e., when new data arrives while the `EPOLLIN` was already raised but `read` hadn't been called or not all of the data was read).

  In the case of a listening socket, the `EPOLLIN` event won't be triggered again until all existing `listen` "backlog" sockets have been accepted using `accept`.
- The `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` flag is used to prevent the "thundering heard" behavior, so only a single `epoll_wait` caller is woken up for each `fd` wake-up event.

  As I pointed out before, for edge-triggered states, an `fd` wake-up event is a **change** in the `fd` state. So all `EPOLLIN` events will be raised until all data was read (the listening socket's backlog was emptied).

When merging these behaviors, and following the example in your question, only one thread is expected to receive the "wake up" call. That thread is expected to `accept` all waiting connections (empty the `listen` "backlog") or no more `EPOLLIN` events will be raised for that socket.

The same applies to readable sockets and pipes. The thread that was woken up is expected to deal with all the readable data. This prevents to waiting threads from attempting to read the data concurrently and experiencing file lock race conditions.

I would recommend that you consider avoiding the edge triggered events if you mean to call `accept` only once for each `epoll_wait` wake-up event. Regardless of using `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE`, you run the risk of not emptying the existing "backlog", so that no new wake-up events will be raised.

Alternatively, I would recommend (and this is what I do) to set the listening socket to non-blocking mode and calling `accept` in a loop until and an `EAGAIN` (or `EWOULDBLOCK`) error is raised, indicating that the backlog is empty.

---

**EDIT 1: Level Triggered Events**

It seems, as Nathaniel pointed out in the comment, that I totally misunderstood the question... I guess I'm used to `EPOLLET` being the misunderstood element.

So, what happens with normal, level-triggered, events (NOT `EPOLLET`)?

Well... the expected behavior is the exact mirror image (opposite) of edge triggered events.

For listenning sockets, the `epoll_wait` is expected return whenever a new connected is available, whether `accept` was called after a previous event or not.

Events are only "merged" if no-one is waiting with `epoll_wait`... in which case the next call for `epoll_wait` will return immediately.

In the context of the example given in the question, thread B is expected to "wake up" due to `epoll_wait` returning.

In this case, both threads will "race" towards `accept`.

However, this doesn't defeat the `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` directive or intent.

The `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` directive is meant to prevent the "thundering heard" phenomenon. In this case, two threads are racing to accept two connections. Each thread can (presumably) call `accept` safely, with no errors. If three threads were used, the third would keep on sleeping.

If the `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` weren't used, all the `epoll_wait` threads would have been woken up whenever a connection was available, meaning that as soon as the first connection arrived, both threads would have been racing to accept a single connection (resulting in a possible error for one of them).

Comment: This answer does a great job of explaining what happens if you have `EPOLLET | EPOLLEXCLUSIVE`. But the question is about what happens if you set `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` but *don't* set `EPOLLET` :-)

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith , I'm sorry I misinterpreted... I guess I thought edge triggered was the least understood one. Anyway, I updated the answer to reflect non-edge triggered behavior.

Comment: thanks for the update! It's good to see that I'm not the only one with the intuition that thread B should be woken, but, well... do you have any evidence beyond intuition? Because see the answer I just posted...

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith, I can probably write a test and add it to my answer (it might take me a bit of time), but I think that it Thread B keeps sleeping, it's an implementation (or documentation) error. Events shouldn't be merged when waiting on a level-triggered `epoll_wait`. They should only be merged if no-one is waiting.

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith , I added code to test the question. Thread B is indeed woken up even though `accept` wasn't called before the second client connected. You can run / tweak the code if you like, but I also posted the results.

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith , P.S. notice that the kernel layer completes the TCP/IP handshake before pushing the socket to the application... so `connect` occurs before `accept`. This is the norm on newer systems.

Comment: well, that's very mysterious :-). I'm still not 100% convinced, because it's hard to prove a negative through testing. (E.g. maybe if the two `connect` events come in fast enough it breaks with 1/10,000 probability?) So I'm thinking I'll wait on accepting an answer until we have a more definitive understanding based on either reading the code or "word of god" from the maintainers. But in the mean time this bounty is about to expire and you've certainly earned it, so here you go :-)

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith , I feel like I'm not fully understanding your concern. In this case it's possible to prove the different options. If the events are merged into a single event, one of the `epoll_wait` calls would return without any events, dropping one of the client connections. On the other hands, both threads returning simultaneously causes a specific printout flow in relation to client 1. If the question is about events merging - than the answer is that events **will** merge if no one is waiting for `epoll_wait` to return or if multiple events happen before `epoll_wait` can return.

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith - I didn't notice you accepted the answer - thank you 

Comment: you found that for level-trigged + `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE`, when two `connect` calls come in, two threads are woken. My concern is whether this is guaranteed to happen 100% of the time, or whether there's some weird race condition that you didn't hit where only one thread wakes up.

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith I believe there's a chance that level-triggered events will be merged if they happen in quick succession, **before** `epoll_wait` had returned (an internal `epoll` lock race). Meaning thread A will return from `epoll_wait` with two connections to accept. I don't think `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` effects this behavior .... P.S. I'm reading through [a 2014 series of blog posts that go through the `epoll` source code](https://idndx.com/2014/09/01/the-implementation-of-epoll-1/). This under the hood look explains a lot about what we can expect and you might enjoy it.

Comment: There is *no* guarantee *at all* on which threads will be woken. Believe it or not.

Comment: @fpbhb, I know you're right, it's even in the test results ;-) ... I guess that in my head I defined thread `A` as the thread that woke up first. I didn't think of it as a specific thread as much as a comfortable way to write "the first one"....

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial answer, but Jason Baron (the author of the `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` patch) just responded to an email I sent him to confirm that when using `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` in level-triggered mode he does think it's possible that two connections will arrive but only one thread will be woken (thread B keeps sleeping). So when using `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` you have to use the same kinds of defensive programming as you use for edge-trigged epoll, regardless of whether you set `EPOLLET`.

Comment: I think the issue of lost (merged) events only occurs when no thread is waiting for `epoll_wait` to return (see the test in my answer for details). However, event merger with no one waiting for `epoll_wait` to return is a distinct possibility that `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` wasn't designed to defend against.