# Linux TCP socket: client has sent data but server still blocks on read()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a simple client-server example using TCP socket on Linux. The server listens on the loopback address. The client connects to server and sends some integer plus an "END" string to mark the end of data. Server reads the numbers, add them all and returns the total sum. However, my server sometime blocks on `read()` even though the client has sent all the data successfully.

Here's the code:

server.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define BACKLOG 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int down_flag = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sfd < 0) {
        perror("Create server socket error: %s\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Bind socket to loopback address */
    memset((void *) &addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
        perror("Bind server socket failed");
        goto _exit;
    }

    if (listen(sfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("Listen failed");
        goto _exit;
    }

    ssize_t num_rd = 0;
    char buf[100] = {0};
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Waiting to accept a connection...\n");
        int cfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL);
        printf("Accepted socket fd = %d\n", cfd);
        result = 0;
        while ((num_rd = read(cfd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
            /* Ensure the buffer is 0-terminated */
            buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;
            printf("Read data: %s\n", buf);

            /* Handle commands */
            if (!strncmp(buf, "DOWN", sizeof(buf))) {
                down_flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(buf, "END", sizeof(buf))) {
                break;
            }
            /* Add received summand */
            result += atoi(buf);
        }
        if (-1 == num_rd) {
            perror("Read error");
        }

        /* Send result */
        sprintf(buf, "%d", result);
        ret = write(cfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (-1 == ret) {
            perror("Write error\n");
            goto _exit;
        }
        close(cfd);
        /* Quit on DOWN command */
        if (down_flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
_exit:
    close(sfd);
    return 0;
}
```

client.c:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int ret;
    int data_socket;
    char buf[100] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    data_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (-1 == data_socket) {
        perror("Create client socket error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Connect to server socket */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    ret = connect(data_socket, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (-1 == ret) {
        perror("Connect error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Send arguments */
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        ret = write(data_socket, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
        if (-1 == ret) {
            perror("Write error");
            break;
        }
    }
    strcpy(buf, "END");
    ret = write(data_socket, buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
    printf("write %s to socket, ret = %d\n", buf, ret);
    if (-1 == ret) {
        perror("Write to socket error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Read the result */
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    ret = read(data_socket, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (-1 == ret) {
        perror("Read from client socket error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;
    printf("Result = %s\n", buf);
    close(data_socket);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Run the client a few times and the server will be blocking on the `read()` call at some points:

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do ./client 3 4 5 6; done
write END to socket, ret = 4
Result = 18
write END to socket, ret = 4
```

Server output:

```
$ ./server
Waiting to accept a connection...
Accepted socket fd = 4
Read data: 3
Read data: 4
Read data: 5
Read data: 6
Read data: END
Waiting to accept a connection...
Accepted socket fd = 4
Read data: 3
```

The server is blocking on `while ((num_rd = read(cfd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)` line.

Edit: My question is why the `read()` blocks. AFAIK, `read()` will block until there's at least 1 byte of data to be read from the socket. In this case, the client has sent more data than the server has read, so I think there's available data to be read from the socket. So why does `read()` still block?

Comment: Log the total number of bytes sent and the total number of bytes received. You'll find that they are equal. So `read` should block since all the sent data has been received.

Comment: Why not use send and recv calls instead of read and write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of the issue is that the code tests for the first message in a buffer and ignores the possibility that the same buffer might contain multiple messages, partial messages or any other combination (see **edit**). For this reason, the message `END` is sometimes overlooked and the `read` loop never terminated.

The code assumes that a **single** `read` will receive exactly what a **single** `write` call had sent.

This is highly inaccurate, rarely true and might work only sometimes, when both client and server are on the same machine.

A single `read` might read 2 `write` calls simultaneously, or it might read half a `write` call and then another 1.5 `write` calls later on...

TCP/IP (unlike [UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446491/tcp-stream-vs-udp-message)) is a [streaming protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842357/frame-based-and-stream-based-protocols/48845071#48845071) and has no knowledge of message boundaries.

---

**EDIT**:

To clarify (as requested in the comment), imagine a call to `read` collects the following data `"1234\0EN"` (the next `read` will collect `"D\0"`)... what does the program do?

Another possible situation is that all `writes` are read in one go. i.e, `buf` contains the string `"3\04\05\06\0END\0"`.

What happens within the loop at this point?

In this example scenario, the `if` statement (`strncmp(buf, "END", sizeof(buf))` is always `false` (and unsafe), resulting in a situation where the server never breaks from the `while(read)` loop.

Since the `while` loop continues, the server will attempt another `read` when there's no data available, resulting in the server blocking until the client will send additional data.

Comment: Thanks. However this still doesn't help me to understand why the `read()` blocks in this case, or to say it your way, this `read()` reads 0 `write()`.

Comment: @theman ... hmmm, I'll edit my answer with more details, but consider a situation where `read` gets `"1234\0END\0"`. When does the `while` loop break?

Answer (score 3):

The null terminator needs to be immediately after the data that was read, not just at the end of the buffer. Otherwise when you try to treat the buffer as a string, the previous contents will be part of the string.

```
buf[num_read] = '\0';
```

And to prevent this from writing outside the buffer, you need to subtract 1 from the buffer size when calling `read()`:

```
while ((num_rd = read(cfd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1)) > 0) {
```

The server then blocks because it doesn't recognize the `END` message that makes it break out of the reading loop, and there's nothing more for it to read. It will block until there's either data to read or EOF. It will get EOF when the client closes the connection, but the client doesn't do that until the server sends the result.

However, I think your whole design may be doomed. TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't have message boundaries. Each call to `write()` in the client doesn't necessarily result in a single `read()` in the server, consecutive writes can (and usually will) be concatenated. You'll need to redesign your protocol to handle this.

Comment: This answer nicely sums up the usual suspects:)

Comment: I'm aware that `consecutive writes can (and usually will) be concatenated`. However, my main concern here is why the `read()` would block.  AFAIK, `read()` will block until there's at least 1 byte of data to be read from the socket. In my case, the client has sent more data than the server has read, so I think there's available data to be read from the socket. So why does `read()` still block?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain why it's blocking. If it doesn't recognized the `END` message, it calls `read()` again, so it's waiting for the client to send more data, but the client has finished sending and is waiting for a response.

Comment: tcp has a chance.

Comment: so you both have made a mistake. check it out

Comment: Check what out?

Answer (score 1):

most straight-forward is to use a `poll()`.

upd:
i think real cause of the stuff written in other answer.  you wanna pipe where you have a stream.
But
you can try this

```
SOCKET q = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
bool c = 1;
setsockopt(q, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
```

Finally

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <poll.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr = { AF_INET , htons( 8888 ) /* btc port */ , htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK) };;
    int down_flag = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    bool c = !false;
    enum { buf_size = 1025 };
    char buf[buf_size] = {0};
    int bc = 1024;    

    int data_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    setsockopt(data_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(data_socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(data_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(data_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(data_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (int *)&bc, sizeof(bc));
    setsockopt(data_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (int *)&bc, sizeof(bc));
    ret = connect(data_socket, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (-1 == ret) {
        perror("Connect error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setsockopt(data_socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));    /* Send arguments */

    struct pollfd pfd[1];
    int nready;
    pfd[0].fd = data_socket;
    pfd[0].events = POLLOUT;

    for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++)
    {
        nready = poll(pfd, 1, 15 * 1000);
        // if((pfd[0].revents & (POLLOUT|POLLHUP))) printf("tray \n" );
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        strcpy(buf, argv[k]);
        ret = write(data_socket, buf , 99);
        if (-1 == ret) {
            perror("Write error");
            break;
        }
    }

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    strcpy(buf, "END");
    nready = poll(pfd, 1, 15 * 1000);
    ret = write(data_socket, buf, 99);
    printf("write %s to socket, ret = %d\n", buf, ret);
    if (-1 == ret) {
        perror("Write to socket error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Read the result */
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    pfd[0].events = POLLIN;
    nready = poll(pfd, 1, 15 * 1000);
    ret = read(data_socket, buf, 99);
    if (-1 == ret) {
        perror("Read from client socket error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("Result = %10s\n", buf);
    close(data_socket);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <poll.h>


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr = { AF_INET , htons( 8888 ) /* btc port */ , htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK) };;
    int down_flag = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    bool c = !false;
    int bc = 1024;    

    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sfd < 0) {
        perror("Create server socket error: %s\n");
        return 0;
    }
    setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
    setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (int *)&bc, sizeof(bc));
    setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (int *)&bc, sizeof(bc));
    /* Bind socket to loopback address */
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
        perror("Bind server socket failed");
        goto _exit;
    }
    setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));

    if (listen(sfd, 128) == -1) {
        perror("Listen failed");
        goto _exit;
    }

    ssize_t num_rd = 0;
    enum { buf_size = 1025 };
    char buf[buf_size] = {0};

    struct pollfd pfd[1] = {{0}};
    int nready;

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Waiting to accept a connection...\n");
        int cfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL);
        printf("Accepted socket fd = %d\n", cfd);
        result = 0;
        pfd[0].fd = cfd;
//      pfd[0].fd = sfd;
        pfd[0].events = POLLIN;
        while (!false) {
            memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            nready = poll(pfd, 1, 15 * 1000);
            num_rd = read(cfd, buf, 99);
            if (num_rd <= 0) break;
            buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';
            printf("Read data: %s\n", buf);

            /* Handle commands */
            if (!strncmp(buf, "DOWN", strlen(buf))) {
                down_flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(buf, "END", strlen(buf))) {
                break;
            }
            int temp = 0;
            int f = sscanf(buf, "%d", &temp);
            if (f != 1)
            {
                printf("and then \n" );
                return (0);
            }
            result = result + temp;
        }
        if (-1 == num_rd) {
            perror("Read error");
        }

        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        sprintf(buf, "%d", result);
        pfd[0].events = POLLOUT;
        nready = poll(pfd, 1, 15 * 1000);
        ret = write(cfd, buf, 99);
        if (-1 == ret) {
            perror("Write error\n");
            goto _exit;
        }
        close(cfd);
        /* Quit on DOWN command */
        if (down_flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
_exit:
    close(sfd);
    return 0;
}
```

also one size for all stuff there. After one write read_buffer should be full so others wait until read is finished up

run:
`./serv`
`for i in {1..100}; do ./client 3 4 5 6; done`

also on github:
https://github.com/alexeyneu/BlockZero/tree/master/onemore

edit:
with 1kb/command looks like it will hold against some big transfers. It's minimum for SO_XXX buffers

Comment: How does this solve the underlying problem...? Can you identify the underlying problem? If not, why answer?

Comment: @Myst looks like you just don't know what `poll()` does . pumping bulk of empty `read`'s with a `while()`  is bad stuff for sure.  it's not even your question

Comment: I am the author of the [facil.io framework](http://facil.io), which is a C framework for web and network applications. I know what `poll` does. However, `poll` won't solve the problem, because the issue with the code in question isn't related to polling or to non-blocking IO. The issue with the code is that the design tests for the first message in a buffer and ignores the possibility that the same buffer might contain multiple messages.

Comment: P.S., I didn't downvote the answer because I think you're only trying to help, which is good. However, I think this doesn't answer the question. It is more of a "here's another approach that could help you". Also, looping on `read` is a common (and valid) approach when handling blocking IO.

Comment: Yeah. we see one of those now

Comment: @Myst haha  why then you dont know this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479760/c-socket-recv-and-send-all-data#comment50470059_13479835 . if used with socket opt i've mentioned it should do the trick

Comment: Maybe my comments weren't clear. I know how [`poll` works](https://github.com/facil-io/cstl/blob/ff251c2d7ce521e40f95a96cf09998c8e7153c97/stl_slices/104%20sock.h#L296-L343), as well as [`epoll` and `setsockopt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582560/how-does-epolls-epollexclusive-mode-interact-with-level-triggering/41730177#41730177), as you can tell from my code examples. But in your solution, you are **moving the problem** from `write` to `poll` - you aren't **solving** the problem. The problem is in a different place.

Comment: @Myst thats may be. i prefer `poll()` to non-blockin write that blocks and all this.